# Unable to get Value from based on conditions in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset in this form:

```
col_1     col_2    col_3    col_4     col_5

0          0        0        0         Nan
0          1        Nan      1         1
1          0        1        0         Nan
0          0        0        0         0
```

Now, I want to create a new column such that for any particular row, if any of the column values is 1, then the output should be 1.. For example, in above dataset, the new column will have second and third row as 1...

SO, I have tried this approach:

```
if ((df['col_1]==1) | (df['col_2']==1) | (df['col_3']==1) | (df['col_4']==1) | (df['col_5']==1)):
    df['new_column']=1
else:
    df['new_column']=0
```

This code was giving me error.

So, I tried a different approach.

```
lists = ['col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4','col_5']
for i in lists:
   if(df[i]==1):
       df['new_column]==1
    else:
        df['new_column']==0
```

This code is again giving me wrong values...

Can someone please help me in solving it as I am beginner in pandas and stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use comparison to 1 (with [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)), aggregate with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) per row (`axis=1`), then perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df.eq(1).any(axis=1), 'new_col'] = 1
```

output:

```
   col_1  col_2 col_3  col_4 col_5  new_col
0      0      0     0      0   Nan      NaN
1      0      1   Nan      1     1      1.0
2      1      0     1      0   Nan      1.0
3      0      0     0      0     0      NaN
```

If you prefer a 0/1 output:

```
df['new'] = df.eq(1).any(1).astype(int)
```

output:

```
   col_1  col_2 col_3  col_4 col_5  new
0      0      0     0      0   Nan    0
1      0      1   Nan      1     1    1
2      1      0     1      0   Nan    1
3      0      0     0      0     0    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.. But can you please tell me where i was wrong with my approach.. What modifications I can do in my code to get the correct values..

Comment: @Patrik it was wrong to try to use `if` without a loop, and it would have been "*wrong*" to use a loop as it's an anti-pattern with pandas. What I showed you is the pandas way ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.assign(col11=df1.apply(lambda ss:(ss==1).any().astype(int),axis=1))

  col_1  col_2 col_3  col_4 col_5  col11
0      0      0     0      0   Nan      0
1      0      1   Nan      1     1      1
2      1      0     1      0   Nan      1
3      0      0     0      0     0      0
```